# How to read xml file using linq

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, class

I have this db.xml file

```
<items>
 <item>
  <title>Title1</title>
  <year>2013</title>
  <categories>
   <category>Category1</category>
   <category>Category2</category>
   <category>Category3</category>
  </categories>
  <count>10</count>
 </item>
 (and so on)
</items>
```

I read like that:

```
var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
               select new
               {
                   Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                   Year = item.Element("year").Value,
                   Categories = item.Element("categories").Value, // I know this is wrong 
                   Count = item.Element("count").Value
           };
```

The problem is how I can read the categories and add them to list?

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    book.Title = item.Title;
    book.Year = item.Year;
    foreach (var Category in Categories)
    {
        book.Categories.Add(Category);
    }
    book.Count = item.Count;
    books.Add(book);
}
```

Comment: You just need to do the same as you did with the first one, just nest it inside, the principle remains the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the list of its elements

**EDITED**

```
var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
       select new
       {
           Title = item.Element("title").Value,
           Year = item.Element("year").Value,
           Categories = item.Descendants("categories").Descendants().Select(x=>x.Value).ToList(),
           Count = item.Element("count").Value
       };
```

Comment: I think this query will produce wrong result. Instead of selecting categories you are returning whole parent element value

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Why? Wont it return the list of categories Descendants?

Comment: Query is incorrect: `Categories` is `List<string>` with just one value: `Category1Category2Category3`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yep, sorry, missed one Descendants() - answer updated

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yep, sorry, missed one Descendants() - answer updated

Comment: @voo now it's correct. I wonder why OP picked answer which was incorrect

Answer (score 5):

It's better to use casting (to `string`, to `int`, etc then reading element's value directly. Here is query which returns integer values for `Year` and `Count` properties. `Categories` are `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
            select new {
               Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
               Year = (int)item.Element("year"),
               Count = (int)item.Element("count"),
               Categories = from c in item.Element("categories").Elements()
                            select (string)c                   
            };
```

If you want `Categories` as `List<string>` then parse categories this way:

```
 Categories = item.Element("categories")
                  .Elements()
                  .Select(c => (string)c)
                  .ToList()
```